# How to Update the Disabled Reason of a CRM Ribbon Button Via Javascript

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a form with multiple custom buttons that are enabled/disabled for multiple reasons, each of which is determined by a Javascript Function that gets called as a part of a Custom Ribbon Enable Rule.  As a part of the Enable Rule JavaScript, I'd like to update the hover text reason the button was disabled: "This record is missing Yada Yada Yada", "You do not have access", etc.

Currently the default message is "You may not have selected the item that works with this feature.  If you do not have permissions to use this feature, contact your system administrator."

Is it possible to updated it from within the enable rule? (yes I know it would be unsupported)  If so, how?

I'm guessing I'd use JQuery, but I'm not familiar enough with selectors to select that div...

```xml
<span 
    class="ms-cui-tooltip" 
    id="new_inquiry|NoRelationship|Form|NEWNEW.Form.itt_inquiry.MainTab.MoveTo.StudentMovement_ToolTip" 
    role="tooltip" 
    aria-hidden="true" 
    style="left: 405px; top: 135px; visibility: hidden; position: absolute; min-width: 210px;" 
    unselectable="on">
    <div class="ms-cui-tooltip-body" unselectable="on">
        <div class="ms-cui-tooltip-glow" unselectable="on">
            <h1 unselectable="on">Movement</h1>
            <div class="ms-cui-tooltip-description" unselectable="on">Movement Description</div>
            <div class="ms-cui-tooltip-clear" unselectable="on"></div>
            <hr unselectable="on">
            <div class="ms-cui-tooltip-footer" unselectable="on">
                <span class=" ms-cui-img-16by16 ms-cui-img-cont-float" style="vertical-align: top;" unselectable="on"></span>
                <div unselectable="on">This button is currently disabled.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ms-cui-tooltip-description" style="width: 90%;" unselectable="on">
                You may not have selected the item that works with this feature.  If you do not have permissions to use this feature, contact your system administrator.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like the following:

```
var btnId = "new_inquiry|NoRelationship|Form|NEWNEW.Form.itt_inquiry.MainTab.MoveTo.StudentMovement_ToolTip";
var btnCls = "ms-cui-tooltip-description"";
var newText = "New button description";
$("#" + btnId + "." + btnCls, window.parent).text(newText);
```

This looks  for an element with a specific id and class on the parent (ribbon) window and changes its text;
Not tested though , you might need to tweak it a bit.